# LNK2005 error when mixing static and dynamic libs

Tags: c++, dll, static, mixing, libs

I am trying to create DLL `ficus.dll` which links to a static lib `utils.lib`, and a dynamic lib (called `crux.dll` using `crux.lib`)

When generating `crux.dll`, I also included `utils.lib` as part of it.

I am getting these errors when linking

> 1>crux.lib(crux.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: char __thiscall
>   std::basic_ios >::fill(char)"
>   (?fill@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEDD@Z) already
>   defined in Utils.lib(BaseTypes.obj)

I have already checked that crux/utils/and ficus are all compiled with the same /MTd flag.

Is there a way to avoid these link errors (besides using `/FORCE:MULTIPLE`)?

Thanks.